# C# Detect file moves trough different folders

Tags: c#, move, filesystemwatcher

I want to detect every filechanges on a specific folder (except data changes). I decided to use System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to manage that.

```
// 
// fileSysWatchFile
// 
this.fileSysWatchFile.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.fileSysWatchFile.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
this.fileSysWatchFile.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName;
this.fileSysWatchFile.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.fileSysWatchFile.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSysWatchFile_Created);
this.fileSysWatchFile.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSysWatchFile_Deleted);
this.fileSysWatchFile.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(this.fileSysWatchFile_Renamed);
```

As far as good... New files are detected. File deletes are detected. File renames are detected.

When I move a file to a subfolder it detects first a file delete and then a new file create.

I'd expect that a move is the same as a rename except the path. Seems that it isn't. Can I detect file moves in a save way?

By the way... I only want to detect file changes and not directory changes.

**Edit:**

Additional Info why I have to detect moves and can't live with delete, create:

I want to replay the same changes on an other drive. If I get a delete first, I delete the shadow file. Then I get the create file event and the original file is already lost :-(.

So I have a drive A which is the watched drive...
And a drive B which has files with the same filenames.

All file changes exept data changes should be replayed on drive B.

Comment: The main problem is that I can't say how long the time is between the delete and the create event. Since this I can't implement a save workaround by detecting it by a delayed path check.

Comment: Anything more than a few seconds would be a very surprising value for a file move, since windows really just updates the file path, even if it said it's a delete + create

Comment: AFAIK FileSystemWatcher is a best-effort approach. There's a limited notification buffer, and when that's full, notifications will be silently dropped. So it's possible that your app might miss some events when the system is busy.

Comment: I don't think that something is missing since I get delete and create events.

Answer (score 1):

The File delete / File create functionality is what is behind a file move. It's similar to rename if you are just moving a file from a folder to a folder, but what about if moving a file from  one disk to another, or moving a file between machines?

And, If I'm watching a specified folder, as long as the file is not there, it might as well have been deleted :)

If you are sure that you want to catch file moved "events" (from a watched folder to a watched subfolder), I would maintain a list of recently deleted files, and upon every file created event, check if the file is it that list, indicating a de facto file move.

Comment: exactly... I have to make a differnce between on disk moves and moves to an other disk... please see my added infos to understand my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you cant do that with the Distributed File System Service? There are also other solutions for file replication, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: if move to an other disk is performed I even would get only a delete event. That's not the situation I have...

Comment: I don't want to replicate the files. The data is different. Only the file names and the relative path from disk is equal.

Comment: So, File from A moves to disk C -> you should delete it from B;


File from C moves to disk A -> you should create it on B;

File from A moves to disk A -> you should movie it on B;

is that correct?

Comment: No. File from A moves to an other folder in A. Corresponding file (with other data) in B should also be moved (and not deleted) on the same relative folder in B.

Comment: In that case, use a list of "deleted" files, and just add the file on the list in the deleted event. In the created event, if the file is on the list, move it, and use some timer event to delete really deleted files.

Comment: @SWeko No, it doesn't. On file system level the IRP for file rename/move is sent, not delete+create

Comment: Okay and how can I get this IRP in the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: @Eugene: Even if the file is moved across drives? Or across a network?

Comment: @SWeko there's no Rename operation then - it's copy + (possibly) delete. So this case is not applicable to original question.

Comment: @Eugene The question is about moving files, the rename fires the Renamed event :)

Comment: @SWeko re-read the question. "When I move a file to a subfolder", which on the FS level is performed using the same IRP. So it is renaming unless some badly written application doesn't recognize that source and target are on the same disk.

Comment: @Eugene: "Move a file to a subfolder" translates to FSW firing a "Deleted" and "Created" event handler AND to a simple file descriptor change by the OS. The badly written application in question is the FileSystemWatcher class in the .net framework. It behaves in that way so that all moves can be treated the same, because it's usual use case is watching the files for a single drop-off folder. And I agree that it's far from ideal for the above scenario, where a whole disk is monitored.

Comment: @SWeko If we take correct application which understands that moving from C:\x.txt to c:\1\x.txt is a rename, it would be rename (and it will arrive as rename to the file system driver and to FS filter drivers). I don't know what FSW would report in this way, but if it reports two operations (even for consistency), that's bad. Now if we take badly written application, it will perform Move by making a copy, then deleting the file. In this scenario FSW would behave correctly. So there can be two cases of bad code - FSW or the application that does Move.

Answer (score 1):

You can use file system filter driver to track file rename operation. Actually, FS Filter is better approach, than FileSystemWatcher. FileSystemWatcher doesn't provide reliability and flexibility for certain cases (you can see the number of questions regarding FileSystemWatcher and it's glitches and limitations).

FS Filter lets you track the requests as soon as they reach the file system.

You can write your own filter driver, or use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product.

Comment: So there is no free solution or codesample? I guess you want to sell your program ;)

Comment: Why not, Windows Driver Kit contains a sample FS filter driver. But in general kernel-mode development is very time-consuming and requires quite serious competence. This is why we offer the solution which lets any developer get all benefits of the FS filter driver without hand coding in kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real solution of the problem, but I managed to have a quick and dirty solution:

First I am buffering all events for a while (tested with 100ms but we will see how fast it can go).

If a event is 100ms in the buffer I check if there is a depending other event also in there. So for Delete I search all creates and for create I search all deletes.

If I find one I replace the two events with only one move event.

There are some riscs with this workarround:
1.) I can't say what comes first, delete or create. Seems that this is every time different 
2.) If the delay is to short, the file is deleted and lost :-(

But as long as I have no better solution I have to live with this.